# Как лучше написать этот код с условием и циклом?

Tags: javascript

Задали задачку, которая должна принимать от пользователя пару аргументов и выводить на их основе арифметическую таблицу.

Сам код вывода результата в таблицу я ещё не продумал (здесь он заменён условной конструкцией alert ('some code'), т.е. на данный момент я планирую сунуть вторую часть на это место), то будет вторая часть Мерлезонского балета. Сейчас тружусь над первой (код прикреплю): сам процесс отбора данных, введённых пользователем.

Привожу код в том виде, в котором он есть (без цикла всё работало), т.к. мне пора идти. Надеюсь, что в течении дня кто-нибудь подскажет, что к чему. 
Занимаюсь самообразованием, спросить могу только у вас, дамы и господа.

```
function calculatione () {
  var op, n;

  op = prompt ('выберите операцию', ' "/", "*", "+" или "-"');
  do {
    if (op == '-' || op == '+' || op =='/' || op =='*') {
      n = prompt ('введите натуральное число', 'целое число от 0 до + бесконечности');
    } else if ( n >= 0 && n == integer ) {
      alert('some code');
    } else {
      alert('Вы ввели Неверное значение. Смотрите описание значений в строке ввода');
    }
  } while (true); 
}

calculatione ();
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо узнать, какое условие для выхода из цикла вы хотите использовать. Также, на мой взгляд, лучше вынести все операции в массив, и в `if` проверять наличие элемента в массиве.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, если функция должна принимать **пару** аргументов, что одной переменной n для проведения арифметических операций недостаточно - нужна ещё одна.

Во-вторых, не очень понятно, что именно Вы хотите прогонять в цикле? Циклы используются, например, для перебора массивов - здесь у Вас ничего подобного нет. Если Вы уточните, в чём именно необходимость цикла, возможно, ответ будет другим.

Пока же для Вашей задачи могу предложить такое решение:

```js
function calculatione() {
  var x, y, op; //объявляем переменные
  
  (function getX() {
     x = +prompt('введите натуральное число', 'целое число от 0 до + бесконечности'); //запрашиваем значение x
     if(isNaN(x) || x<0) { //если пользователь ввёл не число или отрицательное число, требуем от него повторить процедуру
        alert('Вы ввели неверное значение. Попробуйте ещё раз');
        getX();
     }
  })();
  
  (function getY() { //здесь аналогичные действия для y
     y = +prompt('введите натуральное число', 'целое число от 0 до + бесконечности');
     if(isNaN(y) || y<0) {
        alert('Вы ввели неверное значение. Попробуйте ещё раз');
        getY();
     }
  })();
     
  (function getOp() { //здесь получаем значение операции
     op = prompt('выберите операцию', ' "/", "*", "+" или "-"');
     switch(op) { //проверяем, что за операция, и на лету осуществляем калькулирование
        case '/':
          alert(x/y);
         break;
        case '*':
          alert(x*y);
         break;
        case '+':
          alert(x+y);
         break;
        case '-':
          alert(x-y);
         break;
        default: //здесь отправляем пользователя снова выбирать операцию, если он ввёл что-то не то
          alert('Вы ввели неверное значение. Попробуйте ещё раз');
          getOp();
     }
  })();

}

calculatione();
```